# Attempt to invoke virtual method boolean com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.isSuccess()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to integrate FireBase Cloud Messaging in my app using the tutorial :

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial-android/

When I'm trying to launch the app, I'm getting a Null Pointer exception :

Here's the logcat :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'boolean com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.isSuccess()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzi.zzh(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzk.zztp(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zza.zzw(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zze.zztr(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Here's my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        //FireBase dependency
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    //FireBase dependency
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        arm {
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
            }
            minSdkVersion 17
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        applicationId "com.nytshft.evyt"
    }
}
 //FireBase
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Note : I don't have an app module in my application. I have a single build.gradle file.**

Does it have something to do with the build.gradle? In the official site, they say to copy json file inside the app folder. Unfortunately my app doesnt have one such folder.Here's the [ProjectView Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xkn6q.png) . Also they say to add some dependency in app's build.gradle. Since I dont have any app folder, I did those changes in the project's build.gradle file.

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java :**

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
```

**MyFireBaseMessagingService.java**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            //Calling method to generate notification
            //sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     * This method is only generating push notification.
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.androidwidget_logo)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: I wonder why my question is being downvoted. :( Please help!

Comment: You have none of your code here, that's why, probably

Comment: Your firebase dependencies are also out of date and you are following a third-party guide rather than the official one, so that's another issue

Comment: @cricket_007 From a FireBase perspective, I'm doing the very same thing which is done in the tutorial I've mentioned. So thought of avoiding the duplication. That's why posted the tutorial link :(

Comment: @cricket_007, Ok. Can u please let me know how do I overcome NPE?

Comment: It is internal to the Firebase code, so no, I can't tell. I just think you should try the latest version because that one could have issues.

Comment: @cricket_007, I used 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1', the one suggested in official firebase site. Still the same NPE.

Comment: Alright, well, without going over that whole tutorial ourselves, it'll be difficult to really help. It would be great if you could show a [mcve] of how you tried to set up FCM in your own code

Comment: @cricket_007, I have updated the java class. Also, when I removed the google services dependencies (classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services') from the build.gradle, NPE is gone. So NPE has something to do with it. Please note that these 2 things are supposed to be added in the project's root build.gradle file. But my project has only one build.gradle :(

Comment: Guys, Any updates? Please help  me resolve NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of investigation, I've finally found what causes the Null Pointer Exception. There was a `google-play-services.jar` residing in `libs` folder of the project.(added for some other module and not for `FireBase`) That conflicts with 
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` which we add for FireBase. 
 
I had to remove the jar from `libs`and added the same as a dependency like this :
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people forgot this dependencie `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'`. The all dependencies of firebase needs their core, you can learn more about this in this [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup), remember to update `firebase-messaging` to last version `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'`.

Let me know if I have helped you and good programming!

Comment: I have added firebase-core. Doesn't help me :(

Comment: The other thing that you need to do is move this: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to the bottom of gradle. In google documentation this line needs to are the last one.

Comment: Did.and updated in the qn. Same result. I suspect does it have something to do with build.gradle. In the google doc, they mention about 2 build.gradle files -- app and project's. I have only 1 build.gradle file which is of root project's. There's no app folder in my proj. Why so?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Android Studio..!!

Comment: With project view, you only have 1 gradle? :O

Comment: I've updated the screenshot of projects view. Kindly check.

Comment: 1) Multi module Gradle files aren't necessary, project could have been imported from Eclipse, for example 2) The core dependency is downloaded even if you don't explicitly compile it, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting. 3) 9.6.1 isn't the latest version, as you claim

Comment: Yes sorry for core suggestion, when I readed the documentation I didn't see that the core just contains firebase analytics, this firebase suggestions... Alll days  I learns new things! According the unupdated documentation yes, according patch notes no... From 9.0 to 9.6 the firebase devs fixed important bugs, from 9.6 to 10.0 just fixed the bug from to many alarms in samsung, then it's not 'too much important'...